# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'logical_delete_flag' in 'field_list'

Tags: mysql

Although there are many questions here similar to what I am encountering right now, the answers that I have tried are not working. Given the following table and trigger scripts, what would be the reason and resolution as to why the captioned topic is being encountered.

```
CREATE TABLE todolist (
    sequence_number INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    to_do_item VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    done_status BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    active_flag BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
    last_action_code VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    create_pid VARCHAR(45),
    create_datetime TIMESTAMP,
    read_pid VARCHAR(45),
    read_datetime TIMESTAMP,
    update_pid VARCHAR(45),
    update_timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    delete_pid VARCHAR(45),
    delete_timestamp TIMESTAMP,
    logical_delete_flag BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE
);
```

---

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER todolist_trigger_on_record_insert
    BEFORE INSERT ON todolist
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            SET NEW.create_datetime = NOW(),
                NEW.create_pid = 'todolist_trigger_on_record_insert',
                NEW.last_action_code = 'INSERT';
        END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

---

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER todolist_trigger_on_record_update
    BEFORE UPDATE ON todolist
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            IF (logical_delete_flag IS TRUE) THEN
                SET NEW.delete_timestamp = NOW(),
                    NEW.delete_pid = 'todolist_trigger_on_record_logical_delete',
                    NEW.last_action_code = 'LOGICAL_DELETE';
            ELSE
                SET NEW.update_timestamp = NOW(),
                    NEW.update_pid = 'todolist_trigger_on_record_update',
                    NEW.last_action_code = 'UPDATE';
            END IF;
        END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

---

Sequence of SQL Commands:

```
INSERT INTO todolist(to_do_item) VALUE ('Prepare for the assignment');
UPDATE todolist SET to_do_item = 'Check on how to start on the assignment' WHERE sequence_number = 1;
```

Then, the error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed using the `OLD` or `NEW` keyword around `logical_delete_flag` in your `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger. To access columns in rows affected by your trigger you need to use one of these keywords based on your scenario.

For you, you should use `OLD` around the column you're testing for TRUE/FALSE.

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER todolist_trigger_on_record_update
    BEFORE UPDATE ON todolist
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            IF (OLD.logical_delete_flag IS TRUE) THEN
                SET NEW.delete_timestamp = NOW(),
                    NEW.delete_pid = 'todolist_trigger_on_record_logical_delete',
                    NEW.last_action_code = 'LOGICAL_DELETE';
            ELSE
                SET NEW.update_timestamp = NOW(),
                    NEW.update_pid = 'todolist_trigger_on_record_update',
                    NEW.last_action_code = 'UPDATE';
            END IF;
        END;;
DELIMITER ;
```